# How can I update the "multiwindow" setting in Tasker?

Tags: settings, tasker

My GS3 just received an OTA update that gave me a multiwindow setting. Cool! Except, I want to turn it off automatically when I'm using apps that take up the full screen (like some games). I can't find this setting anywhere, but I am also pretty new, so I could be missing it. Since the setting is also pretty new, there probably isn't a variable for it. Is there any way to get a list of settings and/or set one by name?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that *Tasker* already supports this. But you can check with the [UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/), which includes a list of available events, states, variables, and actions.

Comment: @Izzy thanks. I've found and scoured the User Guide, but it is dense for sure. Is there an array of settings or something that I can iterate through and maybe find what I'm looking for? Again, I'm new at this :\

Comment: Except for the linked UserGuide, I don't know of any up-to-date "listing". Which leaves you playing with available actions (condition is clear in your case: app in foreground). Not having an S3, I cannot check as MultiWindow is not available on any of my devices. I would check with "Settings" as action. There could also be an addon on Google Play offering that (I don't know by heart, but you might use my [Tasker Ressource List](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/) as a starting point).

Comment: thanks for the link, but i don't speak German :X I tried to find an English version and Google Translate is failing! Sad day...

Comment: The lists (second half of that article) do not contain that much German. It's just the first half, which you can skip. You won't find an English version of that article, as I didn't create any :) But many comments are in English as well.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I don't think there was a way to do this unless you wrote some java script that you ran from Tasker, but I could never get this to work. (If anyone knows how to write this type of script, I'd love to know.)

However, the latest version of the 'Secure Settings' plugin (by intangibleObject) now supports enabling and disabling multi-window mode (without needing root - if that's a concern). I've tested it on my S4 and it works great. It should work with the S3 as well. Note that this version of Secure Settings is the current beta version which was released only a few days ago.  The latest released version on the Play Store doesn't have this option yet.

Also, in answer to the question about listing system settings... you can do this with another app/plugin called 'System Settings for Tasker' by David P. White.  In order to actually get the listing of settings through, you'll need to have root access. Without root, you have to know the setting names another way. This app will only monitor setting values. It doesn't have any mechanism for changing those values.

The setting names for multi-window are:

multi_window_enabled

multi_window_expanded

multi_window_flashbar_shown

A quick side-note here... if you want to show/hide the little thumb selector (the flashbar) you can long press the back key.  This is of course a manual action instead of an automatic Tasker action, but does come in handy if that flashbar is in your way and you don't have a Tasker task set up to deal with it.  The Secure Settings plugin action only manipulates the multi_window_enabled setting and not the others.